# Number of thread per thread pool

Tags: .net, multithreading, iis

I am learning multithreading development, but there is something I don't understand.
I don't understand the relation between the physical CPU and the number of threads per thread pool.

I wonder if the number of threads associated with each thread pool will change depending on the number of web applications hosted?
[You can find here an image about what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNAcF.png)

Comment: Yes, every web application contains different threads. When the number of your web applications increases, the threads will also increase.

Comment: A modern web server usually uses multi-process architecture. Thus, if you have multiple web apps hosting there, they can be conveniently running in separate worker processes (IIS uses `w3wp.exe`) and each has a unique thread pool. Thus, "will change" is less likely to happen. Also physical CPU count has nothing to do with number of threads in a thread pool. When something is hard to understand, go back to an operating system book and review the process/thread chapters.

Comment: Let me know if you have any good resources about this topic.. The think I don't understand is how many threads will be assigned per (thread pool) web application.